# MySQL query to capture the next time in another column

Tags: mysql, datetime, subquery

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `event_tag` (
    `event_tag_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `start` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `end` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tag` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_tag_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `fk_event_id` (`event_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_event_id` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`event_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `event` (
    `event_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `end` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `event_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`) USING BTREE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

The events table defines an event with a start DateTime and an end DateTime.

Each event can have zero or more tags applied to it, but only one at any given time.  Each tag can apply to some or all of the event and has a start end end of its own.  Absence of an entry, or an entry where tag is NULL indicates no tags for that event (or time frame).

Entries in the event table should 'stack'.  That is to say that more recent entries should override earlier entries for the same time frames.

Thus, given an event:

```
event_id    start               end                 event_name
1234        2023-10-20 12:00:00 2023-10-20 20:00:00 bob
```

and a tag:

```
event_tag_id start              end                  tag   event_id
1            NULL               NULL                 foo   1234
```

This query:

```
SELECT
    et.event_tag_id,
    IFNULL(et.start, e.start) AS start,
    IFNULL(et.end, e.end) AS end_date,
    et.tag,
    et.event_id
FROM
    event_tag et
    LEFT JOIN event e 
        ON et.event_id = e.event_id
WHERE
    et.event_id = 1234
;
```

Gives me what I need:

```
event_tag_id start               end                 tag    event_id
1            2023-10-20 12:00:00 2023-10-20 20:00:00 foo    1234
```

However, when I add another tag, starting two hours into the event, and going until the end:

```
event_tag_id start               end                  tag   event_id
2            2023-10-20 14:00:00 NULL                 bar   1234
```

The above query, gives me the following:

```
event_tag_id start               end                 tag    event_id
1            2023-10-20 12:00:00 2023-10-20 20:00:00 foo    1234
2            2023-10-20 14:00:00 2023-10-20 20:00:00 bar    1234
```

but what I need is:

```
event_tag_id start               end                 tag    event_id
1            2023-10-20 12:00:00 2023-10-20 14:00:00 foo    1234
2            2023-10-20 14:00:00 2023-10-20 20:00:00 bar    1234
```

Where the end time for the earlier entry is the start time of the next one.

**Question**
So, in essence, what I need is a (sub)query such that, it will return, for end:

a. the DateTime, if it is set.

b. if NULL, the start of the next earliest tag for that event_id, whose start occurs after its own start time.  (e.g. start for tag foo was 12:00 - inherited from the event - the next earliest start for that event is 14:00).

c. if Null, and there's no other later start times for the same event, the end time of the event.

Is this possible in MySQL, and if so, how to formulate the Query?

Comment: `That is to say that more recent entries should override earlier entries for the same time frames` By "same time frame' do you mean exactly the same start and end time, or any overlap?

Comment: Something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/9tA3HYmy

Comment: @IanNewson ... Any overlap.

Comment: @FriendlyDragon ... yes that works.  Thanks.